# Which Model to use to predict processing time

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Hi I am trying to predict service provisioning process time.

Application Details: It provision a service request on the devices, it means user pushes some configuration on the device.
Following will be the schema of the data or x-axis.

```
RequestType: Create, Modify, Delete
ServiceType: MPLS-L2,L3, ISP,...
Devices Involved: Device-1, Device-2,Device-3
Total Processing time.
Task-1 processing time
Task-2 processing time
Number of order which are inprogress that time.
```

.....

The device processing time vary based on its utilisation, we don't have information of utilisation.
We don't execute the task, we will depend on other system to process it. they have a queue mechanisum, we don't know what is the actual time to process it.

We know the overall processing time.

We have lakhs of records as such.

Comment: Please don't use local words like `lakh`. Rest of the world doesn't use them or understand them.